# Directive within directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom markdown directive that works fine. Now I would like to use a custom youtube directive within the content that is loaded through that markdown directive. The youtube directive on its own works fine, but as soon as I put it within the markdown file, it gets ignored by angular.

---

**The following works fine (but is not what I want to do):**

.html

```
<div markdown link="contentfile.md">
</div>

<div my-youtube code="'videoidhere'"></div>
```

.md

```
markdown content here
```

---

**The following is what I want to do (but does not work):**

.html

```
<div markdown link="contentfile.md">
</div>
```

.md

```
markdown content here

<div my-youtube code="'videoidhere'"></div>

more markdown content here
```

---

In the second case, it seems as if the YouTube directive is never even called.

*What do I need to do to tell angular to evaluate that directive, after the markdown directive was evaluated?*

---

For completeness, here are the directives:

markdown:

```
app.directive( 'markdown', function( $http ) {
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { link: '@' },
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) 
        {   
            attrs.$observe('link',function(link)
            {
                $http.get('modules/test/files/' + link).success(function(response)
                {
                    var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(response);
                    return element.html(htmlText);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

youtube:

```
app.directive('myYoutube', function( $sce ) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
           if (newVal) {
               scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
           }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: use `$compile` on the source

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/Fyysf/28/ So you probably need to `$compile` the markdown-returned HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do add to the DOM to the `.md` file using the `markdown` directive, but as it isn't compiled, angular does not register it.

Something like this should work:

```
$http.get('modules/test/files/' + link).success(function(response)
{
    var htmlText = converter.makeHtml(response);
    element.html(htmlText);
    $compile( element.contents() )( scope );
    return element;
});
```

Comment: This seems to fix it. Thank you!